# Multiple Joins on Same Table but Different Values

Tags: sql, join, select, ssms

I have an system where users are able to select multiple values from different fields whilst filling out an application.  All of the various values for those multi-values fields are contained in one table, linked to the user's entry application by an application ID.  (I would not have designed it this way but I inherited the db).  I'm trying to write a select statement that queries multiple rows in Table 2 based on unique row in Table 1.

So, tables look like this:

**Application Table (Table1)**

| Application_ID | Applicant_Name | Application_Title | Application_Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1073 | John Smith | John's Application | 07/15/2021 |
| 2104 | Belinda Jones | Belinda Applies | 07/29/2021 |

**Selection Table(Table2)**

| Application_ID | Name | Value | Sort_Order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1073 | State | Texas | 2 |
| 1073 | State | Ohio | 1 |
| 1073 | Color | Red | 2 |
| 1073 | Color | Blue | 1 |
| 1073 | Color | Orange | 2 |
| 2104 | Color | Green | 1 |
| 2104 | Color | Purple | 2 |
| 2104 | State | Delaware | 1 |

I've previously used a left join to pull the values from just one multi-value field in the Selection Table:

select Left(Selection,Value,100) as 'State'

and later in the where cause, define which row by using:

where Selection.Name = 'State'
and Selection.Sort_order = 1

But I can't sort out the best way to write a select statement that pulls all values from the Selection table per Application ID.  I need to have the values from all of the multi-value fields (Name from Table 2) associated with the one Application ID.

Comment: What is your output?

Comment: What platform are you using?  You can group answers into a comma seperated list but how you do it is different on different DBs

Comment: I also don't think this is code you are actually using since `Left(Selection,Value,100)` is a syntax error

Comment: I'm using SSMS.

Comment: I've never had any issues using the Left(table,Value,length) syntax before, so long as I've identified what value I'm looking for in the Where clause.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need some conditional aggregation here -

```
SELECT Applicant_Name, Application_Title, Application_Date,
       STRING_AGG(iif(Name = 'State', Value, ''), ',') STATE,
       STRING_AGG(iif(Name = 'Color', Value, ''), ',') COLOR
  FROM Table1 T1
  LEFT JOIN Table2 T2 ON T1.Application_ID = T2.Application_ID
 GROUP BY Applicant_Name, Application_Title, Application_Date;
```

Comment: I didn't see any logic given to which state to pick -- I think he wants all of them.

Comment: Correct, Hogan, I need all values from all names related to the Application ID, rather than any particular value or name.  Previously I've just had to use a specific value that I could easily define by sort order, but I'm having trouble broadening it out.

Comment: This is what I'm getting:

Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string 'STATE’ THEN Value END) STATE,
 STRING_AGG(CASE WHEN Name = ‘COLOR’ THEN Value END) COLOR

Comment: @eec41516, Try now.

Comment: It's telling me:  'STRING_AGG' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: What is the DBMS Version you are using?

Comment: I'm using SSMS 2017

Comment: Not sure why you are getting this error as SSMS 2017 do support STRING_AGG function. Now Please edit your question and post your final expected result. There might be another method to achieve that.